# How can I combine date-time and time to get datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My data has
df:

```
+-----+---------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|     | date                | time   | home_team          | away_team          |   home_score |   away_score |
+=====+=====================+========+====================+====================+==============+==============+
|  50 | 2014-11-07 00:00:00 | 18:30  | Aalen              | FSV Frankfurt      |            0 |            1 |
+-----+---------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|  51 | 2014-11-07 00:00:00 | 18:30  | Kaiserslautern     | Bochum             |            2 |            2 |
+-----+---------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I want the date and time columns to be combined as:

```
+-----+---------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|     | datetime            | time   | home_team          | away_team          |   home_score |   away_score |
+=====+=====================+========+====================+====================+==============+==============+
|  50 | 2014-11-07 18:30:00 | 18:30  | Aalen              | FSV Frankfurt      |            0 |            1 |
+-----+---------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|  51 | 2014-11-07 18:30:00 | 18:30  | Kaiserslautern     | Bochum             |            2 |            2 |
+-----+---------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

How can I combine the two columns? to get datetime?

Comment: You search for "Python date time", work through a tutorial or two on the `datetime` package, and write code to manipulate this as `datetime` and `timedelta` values.  If you are still stuck, post your code, and we can help with that.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of only `datetime` and not `timedelta`. Now its clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If necessary convert both columns to datetimes and timedeltas use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'] + ':00')
```

If there are already datetimes only add timedeltas:

```
df['date'] += pd.to_timedelta(df['time'] + ':00')
```